# Second Order By overrides first in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, left-join, sql-order-by

In the following code the purchase_price overrides the case order by statement.

```
SELECT
    i.products_mpn, i.active,
    i.distributor_code, i.sales_price
FROM  
    @duplicates d
LEFT JOIN
    import i ON i.products_mpn = d.products_mpn 
             AND i.distributor_code = (SELECT TOP 1 distributor_code 
                                       FROM dbo.kting_ICECAT_import 
                                       WHERE products_mpn = d.products_mpn 
                                       ORDER BY 
                                          (SELECT 
                                               CASE
                                                  WHEN (i.distributor_code = 'x' or i.distributor_code = 'y') AND CAST(stock as int) > 0 
                                                     THEN 2
                                                  WHEN CAST(stock as int) > 0 
                                                     THEN 1
                                                  ELSE 0
                                               END) DESC, 
                                               CAST(purchase_price AS decimal(28,12)))
```

Is there any way to get it to work with ordering by the case statement and then the `purchase_price`?

Comment: provide example data, pls

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ordering of the `CASE` statement to be applied first followed by the ordering of the `purchase_price`, then your `ORDER BY` already has the terms in the right place.  I don't know what `SELECT` is doing in your `CASE` expression, or even if your current query runs.  Something like this may be what you had in mind:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (i.distributor_code = 'x' or i.distributor_code = 'y') AND
                   CAST(stock as int) > 0 THEN 2
              WHEN CAST(stock as int) > 0 THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END DESC, 
         CAST(purchase_price AS DECIMAL(28,12))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the ORDER BY SELECT. I had used columns from the left join "i.distributor_code" should just have been distributor_code